# how to join 2 related tables using postgres functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase

I have a **recipes** table with columns `recipe_id, product_name, instructions` and I have **instructions** table with columns `recipe_id, instructions`.

columns instructions and recipe_id in **recipes** table is the same number that points to `instructions` table.

I was using supabase client and tried to join them like this:

```
  let { data, error, count } = await supabase
    .from('recipes')
    .select(
      `*,
    instructions(instructions)
    `,
      { count: 'exact' }
    )
    .eq('id', id);
```

But the returned data had instructions as an object:

Recipes table:

```
| recipe_id | instructions | product_name |
|-----------|--------------|--------------|
| 24        | 24           | omelette     |
```

Instructions table

```
| recipe_id | instructions                                     |
|-----------|--------------------------------------------------|
| 24        | '{"root":{"children":[{"children":[{"detail":0,"for…format":"","indent":0,"type":"root","version":1}}' |
```

I want combine it so it looks like this:

```
product_name: "Omelette",
recipe_id: 24,
instructions: '{"root":{"children":[{"children":[{"detail":0,"for…format":"","indent":0,"type":"root","version":1}}'
```

How can I write a function that joins recipe with instructions and returns it as a key instead of another object?

Something that I could call it with **supabase.rpc()**

Comment: Can you provide also some example, like: data in recipe table, data in instructions table, and how you want your joined data to be.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you create a function that returns a table.

I've recreated tables here as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE recipes (
    id int8 PRIMARY KEY, 
    product_name text,
    instructions text,
);
CREATE TABLE instructions (
    instructions_id serial, 
    recipe_id int8 REFERENCES recipes ON DELETE CASCADE,
    instructions int,
    PRIMARY KEY (recipe_id, instructions_id)
);
```

Once you have the table set, then you can create the function that returns a `table`. Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_instructions_for_recipe(recipe_id int8) RETURNS 
TABLE (id int8, product_name text, instructions text, instructions_instructions text) AS 
$$
  SELECT recipes.id, recipes.product_name, recipes.instructions , instructions.instructions
  FROM recipes INNER JOIN instructions
  ON recipes.id = instructions.recipe_id
  WHERE recipe_id = recipes.id   
$$ language SQL;
```

Then, you can call the using supabase-js client:

```
const supabase = createClient(SUPABASE_URL, SUPABASE_KEY)
const { data: receipe_data, error } = await supabase
  .rpc('get_instructions_for_recipe', {recipe_id: 1})
```

[image]